# Problem to write a web application in android development

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget, browser

I find out that while i write url with http:// (example - http://google.com )the browser open the page. But when i write without http:// (ex google.com ) it creates exception.

But as a human behaviour most of time people write url as (ex www.google.com or google.com)except (ex http://google.com )in browser.  Is there any program to solve this problem in android application development.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the url starts with http:// or https://, if not append it in the code and use it.

Comment: can we do other action to make it possible, because if we append this in code . it will shows in the browser as a hardcoded. i want to make application as it is standard browser which run on my pc. Means anything u write in browser. ..u may write www.google.com or u may also write only google.com. but both of case result will same...

Comment: Are u using webview to create a custom browser ? or you want to change the behavior of existing browser ?

Comment: my desire is to open a webpage in browser. when i write page address without http:// .. because browser only open page when u write completely address as (http:  //google.com)